# how to upload audio and move in php

Tags: php, html, audio

Please tell me how to upload an audio file in php?

Problem was that audio is a not move in folder and not upload but insert in database was completely working.

```
if(isset($_POST['audio']))
{

    extract($_POST);
    $audio=rand().$_FILES['audio']['name'];
    $tname=$_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'];
    $path='upload/audio/'.$audio;
    move_uploaded_file($tname,$path);
    $cmd=Insert("insert into post(type,value,date_time)values('audio','$audio',now()) ");
}
```

Comment: You don't have any error handling nor input validation so it could be anything.

Comment: You need to add much more details for us to help. What does "not upload" actually mean? What do you see in your http servers error log file?

Comment: And a side note: you _never_ want to use the file name specified by the client side for operations inside your servers internal file system. You cannot trust anything you receive from the client side. Who knows what the user on the client side want to forge into the request? And there is absolutely no need to keep the file name the client side uses. What for? You _may_ want to store it in the database if you later need it. But _never_ inside your file system.